# Define 2 variables and print them

Tags: macros

I'm just getting started with LaTeX, and I'm already struggling with the very basic stuff.

I create 2 commands, each assigning a value to a variable:

```
\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
```

These variables are set using the commands somewhere at the beginning of the document:

```
\firstname{Kevin}
\lastname{De Coninck}
```

When I try to print the `lastname`, everything works fine, when I try to print the `firstname`, the following error is returned `Use of \@ doesn't match its definition. \@f`

I'm priting inside my document using the following code:

```
\begin{document}
    \@firstname
\end{document}
```

What am I missing here?

**Update: Entire document**

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- CONFIGURATION
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- PACKAGES
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{geometry}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- COMMAND DEFINITIONS
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% Summary: Configure the person's name.
% Usage:   \name{<firstname>}{<lastname>}
%          firstname{<firstname>}
%          lastname{<lastname>}
\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- LAYOUT CONFIGURATION
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\geometry{left=2.0cm, top=5.5cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, footskip=.5cm}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- PERSONAL DATA
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{Kevin}
\lastname{De Coninck}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- ACTUAL DOCUMENT
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \@firstname
    \@lastname
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\makeatletter\@firstname\makeatother`, but you should define a wrapper command as well

Comment: `@` is a special character, in the sense that, in packages, it is considered a "letter", whereas in a document, it is considered an "other", and precluded from use in variable names.  As Christian indicates, you can make `@` function as a letter in documents with the invocation of `\makeatletter`.  This then allows its use in variable names such as `\@firstname`, etc.

Comment: `\newcommand{\printnames}{\@lastname, \@firstname}` in a stylefile or between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` as Christian pointed out and command \printnames in your document.

Comment: I don't get it. Using the code Christian supplies renders `irstname`.

Comment: And it doesn't explain my why I can print the `lastname` property, but not the `firstname`.

Comment: @Complexity: You're not showing the real code, but you should `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around your `\newcommand` usages as well

Comment: Instead of writing `@` in the holder macro, why not just write `CMPLX`, then the macros should the prefixed enough and `\CMPLXfirstname` works out of the box. Macros with `@` in their name is genrally for intenal use and for experienced users.

Comment: A suggestion for `\printname`: `\newcommand{\printname}{%
  \@ifundefined{@firstname}{}{\@firstname} \@ifundefined{@lastname}{}{\@lastname}%
}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm showing all the code that I have right now :-) You should now that I'm just getting started.

Comment: @Complexity: Yes, but it's no document. That fragments are not really useful. Doing it my way, I get no error.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've updated the post with the entire document. It's small, and I just want to print my 2 variables, but it isn't working atm.

Comment: @Complexity: I've used your document right now and adding `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around your `\@...` usages works, as well for the `\newcommand` definitions of `\firstname` etc. The output is `KevinDe Coninck` (you're missing a `\ ` after `\@firstname` this way!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you make that an answer on the question so that I can accept it?

Comment: If you say `\def\@lastname{#1}`, you define the macro `\@` in a very specific way. It is comparable to using `\def\foo#1bar#2{#1: #2}`, here the `bar` is a type of separator for the two arguments and is gobbled when TeX processes the code. In your case, `lastname` is seen as a delimiter for the (not existing) argument. Thus, it is gobbled and `\@` is succesfully expande. If you use `\@firstname` instead, `\@` expects `lastname` to follow and complains about incorrect usage. The call of `\lastname` overrides the definition from `\firstname`, thus only one works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added the usual `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair around the definitions and usage.

Please keep daleif's proposition in mind too: `\CMPLXfirstname` seems to be better and easier.

I've also changed `\RequirePackage` into `\usepackage` (although the first one is allowed too, but rather meant for packages only, not for normal documents)

Now, `@` is special character that is reserved as part of names of internal commands which should not be accessible easily for a normal document user. Outside of packages or class files `@` is not considered to be an allowed letter for command names, so `\makeatletter` changes this (temporarily), permitting `@` to be part of such names and `\makeatother` reverts this.

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- CONFIGURATION
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- PACKAGES
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- COMMAND DEFINITIONS
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

% Summary: Configure the person's name.
% Usage:   \name{<firstname>}{<lastname>}
%          firstname{<firstname>}
%          lastname{<lastname>}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}

 \newcommand{\printname}{%
  \@ifundefined{@firstname}{}{\@firstname} \@ifundefined{@lastname}{}{\@lastname}%
}

\makeatother

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- LAYOUT CONFIGURATION
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\geometry{left=2.0cm, top=5.5cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, footskip=.5cm}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- PERSONAL DATA
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{Kevin}
\lastname{De Coninck}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% -- ACTUAL DOCUMENT
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
    \@firstname\ \@lastname
\makeatother

Or \printname%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do `\firstname` and `\lastname` really need to process arguments if all they do with the arguments is fetching them and putting them at the end of their replacement text?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't wish to use `\makeatletter`..`\makeatother`, you can use
`\csname..\endcsname`:

`\csname @firstname\endcsname`  → `\@firstname`.
`\csname @lastname\endcsname`  → `\@lastname`.

I have written a small wrapper for `\csname..\endcsname`:

The macro `\CreateCsFromName` works as follows:

`\CreateCsFromName<preceding tokens with no curly braces>{ControlSequence}`
→ `<preceding tokens with no curly braces>\ControlSequence`.

If you omit `<preceding tokens with no curly braces>`, i.e., if you leave `<preceding tokens with no curly braces>` empty, then `\CreateCsFromName` will just construct the control sequence token from the name of the control sequence:

`\CreateCsFromName{macro}` → `\macro`

Instead of leaving `<preceding tokens with no curly braces>` empty, you can supply whatsoever commands for (re)defining:

`\CreateCsFromName\long\def{macro}` → `\long\def\macro`

`\CreateCsFromName\long\def{macro}#1#2{First argument: #1, second argument: #2}`
→ `\long\def\macro#1#2{First argument: #1, second argument: #2}`

`\CreateCsFromName\newcommand*{macro}` → `\newcommand*\macro`

`\CreateCsFromName\newcommand*{macro}[2]{First argument: #1, second argument: #2}`
→ `\newcommand*\macro[2]{First argument: #1, second argument: #2}`

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand\CreateCsFromName{}
\long\def\CreateCsFromName#1#{\romannumeral0\InnerCreateCsFromName{#1}}
\newcommand\InnerCreateCsFromName[2]{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}

% raise an error in case \@firstname and \@lastname are already defined:
\CreateCsFromName\newcommand*{@firstname}{}
\CreateCsFromName\newcommand*{@lastname}{}

% commands for silently redefining \@firstname and \@lastname:
\newcommand{\firstname}{\CreateCsFromName\def{@firstname}}
\newcommand{\lastname}{\CreateCsFromName\def{@lastname}}

\firstname{Kevin}
\lastname{De Coninck}

\begin{document}

\CreateCsFromName{@firstname} \CreateCsFromName{@lastname}

\end{document}
```